# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working for footer in iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a footer in `UITableView`. The footer just only contains a `UILabel` and I want adjust footer height depend on `UILabel` so I have use

```
self.tableview.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 140;
self.tableview.sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

It works well on iOS9 but not work in iOS8
[image]

Here is my footer view
[image]
The `UILabel` has constraints: `top=5, leading/trailing=8, bottom=34, line=0, height >= 18`

Here is my code for init footer

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BaseFooterViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    BaseFooterViewCell *myFooterView = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
    myFooterView.contentLabel.text = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
    return myFooterView;
}
```

How can I make it work in iOS8? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.
If you can not understand my problem, please check the [DEMO PROJECT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_poNaia6t8kY041LXV2RDJwNHM/view?usp=sharing)

**UPDATE**
In some case, my footer will more complex, it doesn't only contains one `UILabel`, and also `UILabel`,`UIButton` will have different size for `iPhone` and `iPad`. Therefore, it's really hard to calculate footer height correctly. I still want to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: in view will appear just call  layoutIfNeeded Method will solve your prob

Comment: and you should not give height constraint to label

Comment: @MikeAlter thank you, I have called `in view will appear just call layoutIfNeeded` and `remove uilabel constraint height` but it doesn't work :(.  it will produce the image like my post in iOS8. hope you can check it again

Comment: Yep, it's stuffed in iOS 8. I tried your project and had to set the footer height using heightForFooterInSection to make it big enough. Or you can just require iOS 9 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After test, here is my results

For iOS8, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` **only work** for section header and tableview cell and **not work** for section footer

**BUT** strangely, if my tableview **use both** section header and footer, the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` will work for footer.

Then here is the solution

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // I set UITableViewAutomaticDimension for both footer and header
    self.tableview.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0; // it should be 0 because header is empty
    self.tableview.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    self.tableview.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 140;
    self.tableview.sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
// I return empty view for header
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

For iOS9 and above, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` work correctly

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use this -

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   // return 43;

 CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width, 20000.0f);
    CGSize size;

    CGSize boundingBox = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                                  context:nil].size;

    size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));

    return size.height;
}
```

Please try it , it's work for me or feel free.

Comment: thanks for your help. calculate the footer height programmatically is good idea for my case. but in my case it only a test. in the future my footer will contains more component and it's hard to calculate the footer height correctly. so i'm still looking for the solution using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this seems odd. Your code is correct and you have set your constraints perfectly.

Have you set the label of your footerView with number of lines to 0 ?? Reload the view again if still issue persists.

Comment: This seems to be better suited as a comment rather than an answer.  Can you reword this to be a more concrete answer?

Comment: I have already set the label lines to 0 as I mention in my question

Answer (score 1):

So I got this to work by calculating the height based on the text programatically:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BaseFooterViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableview.delegate = self;

    self.tableview.dataSource = self;

//    Comment these out so that the table will call #heightForFooterInSection
//    self.tableview.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 140;
//    
//    self.tableview.sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    //Gett the cell text content
    NSString* textForCell = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";


    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BaseFooterViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

    BaseFooterViewCell *myFooterView = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];

    myFooterView.contentLabel.text = textForCell;

    // Set the height constraint as an outlet in the cell's class so that you can adjust it to set the
    // right size. Also, The -16 in the andMaxWidth param is to account for the leading/trailing width on the label
    myFooterView.cellLabelHeightConstraint.constant = [self heightForString:textForCell withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0] andMaxWidth:self.view.frame.size.width - 16];

    [myFooterView layoutIfNeeded];

    [tableView layoutIfNeeded];

    return myFooterView;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //this would be just getting the content for the label and calling the heightForString Method
    NSString* textForCell = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";

    // the +39 at the end of the return is to account for the 34point bottom space and the 5point
    // top space on the label
    return [self heightForString:textForCell withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0] andMaxWidth:self.view.frame.size.width - 16] + 39;

}


-(CGFloat) heightForString:(NSString*)string withFont:(UIFont*)font andMaxWidth:(CGFloat)width {

    CGRect rect  = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
                                        context:nil];

    CGFloat height = ceilf(rect.size.height);

    return height;

}




-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 3;
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"aA";
    return cell;
}

@end
```

And your BaseFooterViewCell.h with the added outlet

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BaseFooterViewCell : UIView


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *cellLabelHeightConstraint;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *contentLabel;

@end
```

and the changed code and be downloaded from here:
[Dropbox download of changed code](https://db.tt/c6cflCXd)

And just a side note: if in your actual project your not using the system font and you are using a custom font or alternate font etc... you will need to make that change in the calls to the heightForString Method

[image: Result of my changes on ios 8.1 simulator]

Comment: Have you test on UITableViewStyleGrouped tableview?

Answer (score 1):

Your footer layout constraints is correct and I think you can not use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for footer in iOS 8.

For iOS8, you should calculate footer height programmatically and don’t set estimatedSectionFooterHeigh or set `estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0`

For iOS9 and above you can use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` normally
Please check this refer: https://github.com/ebetabox/DynamicCellSectionHeight

Answer (score 0):

Just give four constraint to label : `Top,leading,trailing and bottom`. Don't give height constraint.

And in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` reload `inputViews` of footeView something like,

```
   [self.tableView.tableFooterView reloadInputViews];
```

**Update:**

Try to implement `heightForFooterInSection` like,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I have tried your solution but it doesn't work. still same error. hope you can check my simple demo project

Answer (score 0):

You need set in IB or in code and remove height constraint

```
[yourLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[yourLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

And after set the text call this

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

in `BaseFooterViewCell` class

Hope this help. I took this from Self Sizing example from Apple

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error `use of undeclared identifier 'DeliveryLabelContentCompressionResistancePriority'`. how to fix it?

Comment: i'm sorry change it DeliveryLabelContentHuggingPriority  this is my constant from my code change it to some float value 900.f or `UILayoutPriorityRequired`

Answer (score 0):

First Thing i want to say is "The magic value you used 140 is actually very close for this text rect". Change this value and you will find it is not working on iOS 9 as well. And remove that height constraint from the label and then check it is not working on both IOS versions. This height constraint is messing a little bit in IOS 8. And thats a height >= constraint probably IOS has a bug.

Now some clarification for **sectionFooterHeight** an **estimatedSectionFooterHeight**. This **sectionFooterHeight** jus give a static value to IOS which it use to size the footer. **estimatedSectionFooterHeight** just improves the performance for example the estimated height should be close to the actual height So IOS does not have to redraw a huge view. (My understanding for [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/footerViewForSection)

And the rest is you have to calculate the size of the label at run time.An then create appropriate footer view and return it.